# unable to access spring boot application deployed in centos 9 server : request time out

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, centos, mysql

My application was developed in Spring Boot, MySql. My server is running on CentOS 9 Stream. port 8080 is ocupied by Jenkins. So I have deployed it in a different port 8081. But my problem is when I am trying to access the API from the postman, it is taking a long time and at last showing message request time out.

How I can resolve it?

I am also facing the same issue in the time when trying to access the MySQL from DBear, it is taking a long time to connect and after that telling that request time out.

After searching in the i think the issue is with the port availability from the server. Guide me so that when I will deploy an application it will be available. I am also Apache web server.

Comment: Are you sure that you want your mysql database accessible from outside your server? Usually database servers are by default configured to only bind to localhost, as other configurations could be possibly dangerous.

Comment: Basic steps would be to check if the server is listening to the right port with `netstat -tulpn`, check firewall rules, check if port is reachable from the outside for example with `nc`, check if you can connect to the database manually. You could also check the server logs (`journalctl -f`) to know whats going on under the hood.